# How to correctly numpy.nanmean and the axis keyword on 3D arrays?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a NumPy array of shape `(3,16,110)`.
I want to take each element in each `(16,110)` array and average it with the other two elements in the remaining 2 `(16,110)` arrays. The resultant array should be `(16,110)` in dimensions.

To show what I mean with smaller `(2,3)` arrays, for example:

```
a= [(0, 2, nan),
    (1, 3, 1)  ]

b = [(1, 3, 2),
     (3, 4, 7)]

c = [(nan, 5, 2),
     (1, 3, 2)]
```

I want to produce an array with dimensions `(2,3)` taking first the average of `(0,1,nan)` then moving to the next element `(2,3,5)` etc...

So is the correct way to do this and take the `nan`'s into account is to use `np.nanmean(3darray, axis=0)`?
I don't really understand the `axis` keyword, I would be grateful if someone could explain :)

Comment: Hi Please refer this page for asking good question which usually get upvoted,which helps in getting good answer [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Compose 3D array from your `a`, `b` and `c`, and play with that `np.nanmean`. When you figure out how it works, you will be able to extend it to your original `(3, 16, 110)`array.

Answer (score 0):

Try these out:

```
import numpy as np

a= [(0, 2, np.NaN),
   ...:     (1, 3, 1)  ]
   ...: 
   ...: b = [(1, 3, 2),
   ...:      (3, 4, 7)]
   ...: 
   ...: c = [(np.NaN, 5, 2),
   ...:      (1, 3, 2)]


d=[a,b,c,b]

np.array(d).shape

>>(4, 2, 3)

np.nanmean(d,axis=0) #removes the first axis

>>array([[0.66666667, 3.25      , 2.        ],
       [2.        , 3.5       , 4.25      ]])

np.nanmean(d,axis=0).shape

>>(2, 3)

np.nanmean(d,axis=1) #removes the second axis

>>array([[0.5, 2.5, 1. ],
       [2. , 3.5, 4.5],
       [1. , 4. , 2. ],
       [2. , 3.5, 4.5]])

np.nanmean(d,axis=1).shape

>>(4, 3)

np.nanmean(d,axis=2) #removes the third axis

>>array([[1.        , 1.66666667],
       [2.        , 4.66666667],
       [3.5       , 2.        ],
       [2.        , 4.66666667]])

np.nanmean(d,axis=2).shape

>>(4, 2)
```

The axis keyword tells you along which axis you will be avergaing. Put in other words, said axis will be removed by averaging.

So what you need specifically is `np.nanmean(d,axis=0)`.